# Creating a zoomed mirror effect

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

[image]I am trying to create a zoomed mirror effect of a video s that the transformation goes something like

```
Input -> Output 
______________      ________________________________________
|Top Section   |  -> |Top Section    + Zoomed top 1/3 Middle| 
|Middle Section|  -> |Middle Section + Zoomed mid 1/3 Middle|
|Bottom Section|  -> |Middle Section + Zoomed bot 1/3 Middle|
______________      ________________________________________
```

I assume this would work as a one-pass complex filter but I don't have the hang of the syntax and so I'm doing it in two passes and at this point the combine with two inputs always throws an error.

My original video is 1080:1920 @ 60 fps.

if I ffprobe the two files I get

```
ffprobe version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Cropped/PXL_20210124_220945291.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:45.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3227 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1080x1920 [SAR 8:7 DAR 9:14], 3022 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 191 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      handler_name    : SoundHandle

ffprobe version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from './PXL_20210124_220945291.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2021-01-24T22:10:31.000000Z
    com.android.capture.fps: 60.000000
  Duration: 00:00:45.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 29957 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 191 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2021-01-24T22:10:31.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: hevc (Main) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m/bt470bg/smpte170m), 1920x1080, 29760 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 59.97 fps, 60 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2021-01-24T22:10:31.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
```

and if I try to do a side by side merge using
(I've tried changing the scale of the cropped video and the rotation but so far I can't get the right combination

```
    ffmpeg -i PXL_20210124_220945291.mp4 -t 00:00:3 -vf crop=in_w*.4:in_h*.35:in_w*.275:in_h*.15, scale=1920:1080 -c:a copy -preset medium -pix_fmt yuv420p -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90 -y Cropped/PXL_20210124_220945291.mp4
    ffmpeg -i PXL_20210124_220945291.mp4 -i Cropped/PXL_20210124_220945291.mp4.mkv -filter_complex 'hstack,format=yuv420p' -c:v libx265 -crf 18 -r 60 -y Combined/PXL_20210124_220945291.mp4
```

always returns

```
[Parsed_hstack_0 @ 0x55cafa398540] Input 1 height 1080 does not match input 0 height 1920.
[Parsed_hstack_0 @ 0x55cafa398540] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_hstack_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
Conversion failed!
```

I can post short clips of the files if that would be useful.

Comment: Your intended transform is unclear to me. Can you illustrate?

Comment: I redrew this in my question...

Comment: Still unclear. Can you make an image example of what you want to do?

Comment: Updated https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHwVA.jpg